# Rails fetching image attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails app, I need to fetch the first image attachment associated with product. Following were my code:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

    def index
        @products = Product.first
        @product_attachments = ProductAttachment.first 
        logger.info "status=Fetching Home Product image=#{@products.product_attachments.attachment.url}" 
    end


end
```

`ProductAttachment` model:

```
class ProductAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base

    mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader
    belongs_to :product
end
```

`Product` model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base


    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :product_category
    belongs_to :location
    has_many :product_attachments, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_attachments, allow_destroy: true
    has_many :variants, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :variants, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? }


    attr_accessor :product_overview_url
    attr_accessor :user_avatar_url

    validates :name, :presence => true
    validates :product_category_id, :presence => true
    validates :payment_type, :presence => true

end
```

This is my view:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center content-title">
                <h3>New York</h3>
            </div>
            <% @products.each do |product| %>
            <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
                <p class="price">USD <%= product.price_cents/100 %></p>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/nuraika/128.jpg" class="img-circle user-thumb" width="52"/></a>
                <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="<%= product.product_attachments%>" width="262" alt="">
                </a>
                <h4>
                    <a href="#"><%= product.name %></a>
                </h4>
                <a href="#">
                    <p><%= product.city%>, <%= product.country%></p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <% end %>

        </div>
```

How can I fetch only one image associated with the product?

Comment: So why don't you try `product.product_attachments.try(:first)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this: 
`html
<img class="img-responsive" src="<%= product.product_attachments.first %>" width="262" alt="">`